# Upload window opened. need to enter file path by python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Hi team,
I have created program where I need to upload file. By clicking on "Upload" , I reach to this window. but here I stuck now. I need to enter path automatically. please help if you have any examples.

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C:\\Users\\Ast1\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')
    Sharepoint ="https://ast.sharepoint.com/sites/ExtTeam_GPS/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=3638f543%2D486c%2D4bca%2D85a7%2D8d86da0a8eb5&id=%2Fsites%2FExtTeam%5FNO%2FShared%20Documents%2FPowerBI%20Datasets"
    driverLink= Sharepoint
    driver1.get(driverLink)
    Em = WebDriverWait(driver1,120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'i0116')))
    Em.send_keys("astemp1@ast.com")
    elm =WebDriverWait(driver1,120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'idSIButton9')))
    elm.click()
    driver1.implicitly_wait(100)
    #elm1 = WebDriverWait(driver1,100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,'Upload')))
    elm2 = driver1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="appRoot"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')
    elm2.click()
    driver1.implicitly_wait(20)
    elm3 = driver1.find_element_by_name('Files')
    elm3.click()
    driver1.implicitly_wait(20)
    #Follwing code is not working.
    Elm4 = driver1.find_element(By.ID('File name'))
    Elm4.send_keys(r'C:\A1\AA1\M1\Input\TblGpsNew.xlsx')
    #driver1.implicitly_wait(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page where you have the `upload button` (entire page), if the below xpath

```
//input[@type='file']
```

`exists` at least one time `1/1` matches then, you can directly send the keys.

Explicitly **no need** to `click` on `upload button` and then interact with the windows pop up.

```
driver1.find_element(By.XPATH("//input[@type='file']")).send_keys("C:\A1\AA1\M1\Input\TblGpsNew.xlsx")
```

Comment: Its throwing error : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: first thing first. Do we have xpath `//input[@type='file']` in HTML DOM ?

Comment: No. Unable to fetch the code of window. its a popup window.

Comment: Do you understand what is HTML DOM ? Don't hesitate to ask if you do not know. Do you know how do we check in HTML DOM that we've a unique marching DOM.

Comment: Actually no, i dont have idea. but i dont know python in details too .. but could reach the above code.

Comment: hmm..Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  this `//input[@type='file']` and see if your desired element is getting highlighted. This you should do on the page where you have upload button

Comment: Hey, i got following xpath: 

/html/body/div[3]/input[1]

/html/body/div[3]/input[2]

Comment: no you need to check the xpath which I have given you.

Comment: No. No matching selector or style

Comment: What if @type='hidden'?